# PXE server, netboot

Tags: pxe

I read a bit about netbooting, PXE, thinclient, diskless and so on and I am still confused with one thing: what components has an image to include in order to be "netbootable"?
Are all the live media netbootable or only [these](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/) images are netbootable?

I can reformulate my questions if for some reasons is not descriptive enough for some readers. Thanks folks!

Comment: I would start with https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/netboot-amd64. Any bootable image can be booted via PXE. Generally, you want to keep the size small, since the whole image must be transmitted over the the network before the machine can continue booting.

Comment: I booted via PXE quite a few distros but some failed, that is why I thought the only these https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/ are netbootable. Why they selected these and then these: Legacy Ubuntu Netboot Images
Netboot images of Ubuntu are available for the following releases:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine)

Comment: I can boot 14.04 and 16.04 but can't boot 20.04 Desktop/Server due to NFS over TCP not available from ip